# Python unable to add message into Thunderbird Mbox

Tags: python, email, thunderbird, mbox

I am using python 2.7 on ubuntu 16.04.

I have been using python to read emails out of mbox files on my pc which were created by thunderbird. I now want to add messages into those mbox files. I shut down thunderbird and then I try to run my python script from the command line. The python script does not give me any error messages at all, but I do not see any new messages being added into the mbox file when I open up thunderbird.

I did look to see if I have a permissions problem. I changed the permissions of the mbox file in linux to: view content=anyone, change content=anyone, execute=anyone.

I run my python script in sudo mode.

Here is my code which I have tried:

```
mboxfile = "/home/jan/.thunderbird/gkzlvipz.default/ImapMail/mail.jan.info/INBOX"

print("opening: "+mboxfile)

mbox = mailbox.mbox(mboxfile)

mbox.lock()

try:

    print("Trying:Begins")

    msg = mailbox.mboxMessage()

    msg.set_unixfrom('author Sat Feb  7 01:05:34 2020')

    msg['From'] = 'info@jan.info'

    msg['To'] = 'ljan@gmail.com'

    msg['Subject'] = 'JL Python Sample message 1'

    msg.set_payload('This is the body.\nFrom (should be escaped).\nThere are 3 lines.\n')

    mbox.add(msg)

    mbox.flush()

    print("Trying:Ends")

except Exception as e:

    # Just print(e) is cleaner and more likely what you want,

    # but if you insist on printing message specifically whenever possible...

    Print("Exception - FAILED")

    if hasattr(e, 'message'):

        print("Error 1: " + e.message)

    else:

        print("Error 2: " + e)    

finally:

    print("Finally")

    mbox.unlock()

sys.exit("PYTHON ENDS: TEST EMAIL SEND FINISHED")
```

The output I get when I run the above script is:

```
*** PYTESTTHUNDERBIRD BEGINS ***
opening: /home/jan/.thunderbird/gkzlvipz.default/ImapMail/mail.jan.info/INBOX

Trying:Begins

Trying:Ends

Finally

PYTHON ENDS: TEST EMAIL SEND FINISHED
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and why I am not getting any error messages.

I'll be most grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: select code in question and use button `{}` to format it

Comment: first remove `try/except` to get full traceback (full error message) - and put it in question. BTW: And maybe when you read full traceback then you will see what is real problem and you resolve it without our help.

Comment: why do you want to add it ? Maybe Thunderbird synchronizes it with mail server and it removes it ? And if you want to send mail then use `smtplib` and use directly mail server - without Thunderbird.

Comment: Hi Furas, Thank you so much for your suggestions. Here is my feedback. (1) I did remove the whole try... to see if it crashes, but it does NOT. It still runs through perfectly. But I do not see a message in the folder. (2) When you ask the purpose, I was just trying to test the functionality to see if I could make it work. If so, then I would prefer to send out messages via Thunderbird itself because these are low volume messages AND if they go out via a client then they are NOT regarded as spam, etc. They have a higher "ranking" in other email systems.

Comment: Also, another thing I want to do, is to delete and move messages in the mbox folder. That was also why I wanted to try adding something. I will write some code to see if I can read and delete a message in the mbox folder in the meantime.

Comment: well, did you check in folder in Thunderbird, or in folder on disk? maybe first check if it add to folder on disk. OR maybe it adds to other folder or adder account.

Comment: I made an interesting discovery. When I took my python script and I tried to read from the folder where I had added messages into it, I found that I could indeed read and see them all!!! But they were not being displayed by Thunderbird! So it is putting them into that mbox folder, but they are not visible in Thunderbird. I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: I use Thunderbird but I always use `smtplib` or `imaplib` or [IMAPClient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/) to work with mails - ie. to download spam for analyze - and few second later I have the same result in Thunderbird because it synchronize it (and I don't have to close Thunderbird to get changes). To send mail I would also use `IMAPClient` and eventually I would add headers used by Thunderbird to imitate this client.

Comment: I have no idea why `mbox` doesn't work. Maybe TB uses something else to keep information (it is based on Firefox which use SQLite to keep some information), or it synchronizes local folders with folders on server and doesn't respect elements which not exists on server.

Comment: Furas, if you can show me how I can imitate the Thunderbird headers, then I would rather do things your way. Then I won't bother with what I was trying above. And a final question: If I am iterating through mbox like this: for msg in mailbox.mbox(mboxfile):   --- how do I find the email key?

Comment: do you mean `print( msg.keys() )` ? I never tried to imitate Thunderbird so I would use Google to search information. OR at start I would use Thunderbird to send few mails to myself, next I would download these mails as files `.eml` and I would open them in text editor to see all headers. I would compare mails to see which headers are the same, which use different values and if these value change randomly or by constant value. I can be only problem: some headers can be added by mail server(s) and I would have to skip them - but I don't know which one to skip (probably last values).

Answer (score 0):

The messages you added to the mbox file aren't showing up in Thunderbird because you didn't update the index (.msf) file for that folder.

In Thunderbird, right-click on the folder name and select "Properties". In the "General Information" tab, read the blurb next to the "[Repair Folder]" button. Then click the folder. This will cause Thunderbird to rebuild the index from scratch — including the messages you've added. (Assuming of course you didn't mess them up in the process.)